# DateTime.FromOADate equivalent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

how can i convert the double value to datetime in jquery ?

1. i have converted the datetime to double value using **.ToOADate()** for some purpose in C#
2. i need to convert it to equivalent DateTime in script.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: So what does the value look like when it arrives in the browser?

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to do that?  OLE Automation dates are not any kind of standard.  `.ToOADate()` is really there for backwards compatibility interaction with older Windows technologies.